# Can't vote to delete migrated question

Tags: support

I stumbled over this question [Looking for software that can assemble large blocks of text from small blocks of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156187/looking-for-software-that-can-assemble-large-blocks-of-text-from-small-blocks-of) a few days ago. It's off-topic, doesn't have a great set of answers, and it's been closed so I went to vote to delete it, but found that there was no option to do so.

The question seems to have been migrated from AskUbuntu.com, but has a 'migration rejected' message and doesn't now exist there anyway. It also seems to have had a bounty awarded on it, and somehow is now locked, but doesn't say it is.

Is this a problem question that's found a bug, or is the reason for the lock not being displayed for some reason (maybe a different bug)?

I flagged it for moderator attention a couple of weeks ago but no-one has, as yet, picked it up.

What to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand what's going on, you need to understand the migration process. When the question was first migrated here, it got locked down on the destination site. That's because the question was now active here, and we don't want people maintaining two different versions of the same question on the two separate sites, but to focus on it in one place.

When the question then got closed as off-topic here, the migration was rejected. This causes two things to happen - the first being that the question gets *unlocked* on the original site and becomes marked as just off-topic rather than migrated. Well, we don't want two versions running around as before, so in order to solve this problem, the question then gets locked here since the focus of the question has shifted *back* to the origin site.

This causes some confusion when the 30 days have already passed, and the migration stub has already been deleted on the origin site. You end up with this closed and locked question on one site pointing back to a deleted question on another. That's just... odd. Migrations have always been a bit of an iffy territory, and part of the reason is because we kind of *made them that way*.

Migration stubs get deleted from the origin site after 30 days, but [**rejected migration stubs never get deleted from the destination site**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224474/are-rejected-migrations-ever-automatically-deleted-from-the-destination-site-sh). When a migrated question gets rejected, it gets closed and locked down and just... sits there. **Forever.** It never gets automatically unlocked and, because it's *locked*, is never seen by the automated cleanup processes that delete questions (even if it is otherwise eligible under other criteria). So we end up with these little rejection stubs sitting around that no one can do anything about.

Part of this can be alleviated by just [*not rejecting things*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167473/apply-the-same-rules-of-migration-to-rejected-migrations). I'm not saying don't ever reject migrations, but if we know the question is completely gone from the origin site, it doesn't make sense to say the migration was rejected and "go look at it on this other site where you can't actually see it." Some questions live on a site for *years* before they end up getting closed and kicked back. Even in this specific case, the question has been sitting here since February of 2012 - that's a whole three years. By not locking these questions and kicking them back if they've been here a long time, we leave them eligible to further moderation actions by the community, or automated cleanup by the system.

But until some of these issues do get worked out, the only thing you *can* do is just flag for a moderator - because they're the only ones who can touch it. Explaining the situation in the flag as you have should get the appropriate response (though it might take a while due to the size of the flags queue).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. The next time I find one of these I'll flag it again and just leave it to fester :)

Comment: It's no more **Forever**: please see [this answer from Shog9 explaining that rejected stubs also get deleted after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287891/263422).