# Why do "homework dump" questions get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, homework

I came across a question with its title in Russian (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847032/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-java)). Nothing but a homework dump:

> You have been hired to write an application for a parking garage to automate the calculation of the fee to park a car in the garage. The fee consists of a minimum flat rate of $2.00. Parking for the first one hour will cost the flat rate. The fee beyond one hour is $0.50 per half hour or part thereof (i.e. if the car is parked for only part of the half hour, say 10 minutes, the charge is still $0.50) up to a $20.00 maximum for 24 hour parking. Assume that no one parks for more than 24 hours.
>
> Test plan Description...

And: **migrated from ru.stackoverflow.com 4 mins ago**

I thought migration happens by moderator actions? Why exactly would a moderator *migrate* such input, instead of closing it, and maybe deleting it?

Edit: the question is now "on hold", but interestingly enough, the "delete" link is missing.

Comment: Maybe the moderator didn't understand English and just figured he'd move it to the main site? (I don't condone that by the way, just trying to figure out what it could be)

Comment: You'd have to ask at ru.meta.stackoverflow.com.  In Russian.

Comment: I've left a comment now that the migration is rejected on the original post.

Comment: Regarding the missing delete button: you can see [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371221/7296893) to add it for meta, at least. Rejected migration stubs are not deletable. Explanation by Animuson [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292227/7296893).

Comment: Presumably, someone(s) over at the RU site saw that the text of the question was in English, and decided that was sufficient reason to migrate it, the language of the title notwithstanding.  Of course, the question was off-topic both places, and language-inappropriate both places, so it should have just been closed as off-topic instead of being migrated.

Comment: I guess this caught someone's attention, because the question is gone now.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've added a comment on Animuson answer, because it was outdated: nowadays, rejected migration stubs do get deleted after 30 days as well.

Comment: It's sort of a triple coil, with a twist. The OP dumps it on ru.SO, they dump it on us, then while it's on hold it gets flushed.

Comment: we already disscuss about this on [meta.ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4091/186999) [in russian] and add special reason for closing. It's strange that post was migrated instead of closed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[From the history of the original post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/868684/timeline), it *looks* like Stack Overflow may be a migration target.  A non-moderator also voted to migrate this over.

Now *why* they chose to do this?  Your guess is as good as any.  Let's just close it, downvote it and move on with our lives.  Someone from the Community team may be better positioned to reach out to them about this as opposed to any of us.

Comment: It is on hold now, but there is no "delete" link?!

Comment: @GhostCat rejected migrations are automatically locked and [deleted after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287891/165773) (unless moderators unlock them)

Comment: "it looks like Stack Overflow may be a migration target" nope, the user just voted to close, it looks like that because its shown as what the final close reason was.

Comment: I've seen more posts that were migrated despite being blatantly off topic in the target all over the SE network. I guess some moderators simply don't want to have to deal with the kids complaining about their questions being closed and decide to push that task on someone else.

Comment: Frankly a lot more questions should be migrated to the appropriate sites; we should be cleaning up stuff that's related to our sites.

Comment: There had been many proposals regarding incorrect migration (including letting the target site to verify the questions), but of course they're still unimplemented.

Comment: Is there a list of non-EN-US stackoverflow sites that I close to migrate to? There are obvious ESL issues with the questions posted in some tags.

Comment: @Jeeped no; only the sites listed in the close-vote dialogue under "off-topic" -> "belongs on another site" are ones *you* can migrate to. To migrate a question to any other site on the network you need moderator powers, i.e. modflag the post.

Comment: @adriaan, I would be happy with a list. I think I can figure out an 'Off-topic, Other' vtc.

Comment: @Jeeped this *is* the list. Just the five (meta, SU, dba, tex, and stats) listed in the close dialogue. **You** cannot migrate a post anywhere else, and these five even only with at least 3 out of 5 close voters. OT-custom/other gives a comment, true, but does not migrate the question.

Comment: @adriaan, Well, this question mentions a ru.stackoverflow.com. I believe there is an ES-ES (*español* or spanish) version as well. I would like to know if there are others.

Comment: @Jeeped yes there are; click the hamburger menu in the top bar and that'll list all sites on the network. Currently Russian, Spanish and Portugese have their own Stack Overflow version, along with the English one of course. I read your comment as whether you can migrate to other sites, and to that the answer remains a firm no. All you can do is leave a comment suggesting the OP to move the question themselves to the correct locale or modflag. Whether the other locales can migrate to the English version without moderator powers I wouldn't know.

Comment: @TylerH: The problem preventing that from working lies in the fact that a migration is considered rejected when the migrated question is closed on the destination site, even for quality reasons (i.e. the question is on-topic but fails to tick some boxes required for it to be answerable). The expectation is that questions are cleaned up *prior* to migration, not after the fact. And if what jwenting speculates about the moderators' attitude towards migration is true, then that is very irresponsible of those moderators (and especially to do so without even consulting fellow network moderators).

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah I have discussed at length ways to rework the migration system into a more automated one elsewhere on Meta but I can't recall where off the top of my head. tl;dr - migration should be way more automatic, and sites should clean up crap questions on their subject migrated to their site, regardless of where said questions were originally posted, rather than, say, SO having to clean up every other site's crap questions.